# error org.json.JSONException: No value for PROJECT_NAME This is my json

Tags: android, json

I am getting the error org.json.JSONException: No value for PROJECT_NAME This is my json

```
{"PROJECTS":[ 
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": "2062",
            "PROJECT_NAME": "OPW 51183"
         },
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": "404",
            "PROJECT_NAME": "404"
         },
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": "2125",
            "PROJECT_NAME": "OPW 50016"
         },
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": ""
         },
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": "2130",
            "PROJECT_NAME": "OPW 51151 63rd & Shirley SEW S"
         },
         {
            "PROJECT_NUMBER": "2159",
            "PROJECT_NAME": "OPW 51226"
         }
        ]

    }
```

and cod is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) 
    {

JSONObject obj=innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);
String projectnumber1=obj.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER");
String projectname1=obj.getString("PROJECT_NAME");
        }
```

Is there is any way to find the key if key not exist then np need to get the value od particular string Help me thanks

Comment: you will not get the value for that parameter while getting response from server side

Comment: how to parse this type of json i have big json but i puted here a small part

Comment: the above code is like, json response is must. while getting json response some time, the key value parameter itself not present.. that time this much error will come surely..

Comment: then i want solution for this only?

Comment: one way is there, better, first find what are the keys are coming in json server side. us this code to get the  keys names first. JSONObject headerCode                                            try {
 Iterator iterate = headerCode.keys();
while (iterate.hasNext()) {
key = iterate.next().toString();
 storeJsonData.add(key.toString().trim());
Log.v("hari", "while loop--key checking----key:"+key);
}
catch(Exception e){
}

Comment: after saw this keys, then use this code to get the pair values.. for ( int i = 0 ; i < storeJsonData.size() ; i++ ) {
 key = storeJsonData.get(i) ;
 Log.v("hari", "Entering ----inside forloop key:"+key);
  if( key.equals("PROJECT_NUMBER")) {
 PROJECT_NUMBER_temp = headerCode.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER");
 Log.v("hari", "inside forloop---PROJECT_NUMBER:" + PROJECT_NUMBER_temp);
 } 
 else if ( key.equals("PROJECT_NAME")) {
 PROJECT_NAME_temp = headerCode.getString("PROJECT_NAME");
 Log.v("hari", "PROJECT_NAME:" + PROJECT_NAME_temp);
 }
  }

Comment: the above code is for used like, find the keys (we dont know, what are all the keys will come,) and get the values from that keys..

Comment: if not understand, give me any sample json url( json format above), at my free time, i will try this and post the code here..bye..

Answer (score 59, accepted):

*Use [has](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to check if key is present in Json. It returns true if this object has a mapping for name.*

like

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (obj.has("PROJECT_NUMBER")) {
        String projectnumber1 = obj.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER");
    }

    if (obj.has("PROJECT_NAME")) {
        String projectname1 = obj.getString("PROJECT_NAME");
    }
}
```

---

*Another way is to use [optString](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29) which returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary. Returns the empty string if no such mapping exists.*

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);

    String projNum = obj.optString("PROJECT_NUMBER"); 
    String projName = obj.optString("PROJECT_NAME"); 
    // and use both values. 
}
```

Comment: I have question that it have 20000 iteration it is possible to store in sqlite because it take much time to store and fetch or any value suggestion?

Comment: I am using orm dao but it take much time in insert but it get fetch fast

Comment: Actually I used ORM Lite but not Green Dao. So can't tell you the comparison. But Green DAO says that it is faster than ORMLIte. So You should also try Green DAO. And make your own choice.

Comment: And if you are saying 20000 iteration about parsing and inserting data into DB, then you should also consider that parsing also takes some time. I think you should also check with my second code snippet where you no need to use if block. SO it will be faster than first one.

Comment: me faced the same issue , and found it. actually i was retrieving the string from json which was no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

// Because if the parameter or variable is not exists into JSON object it won't execute further code and throw exception so its better to use like :

```
try {

            JSONObject data = coupon;



                if(data.has("event_recurring_text")) {

                    if ("".equals(data.getString("event_recurring_text"))) {

                        bundle.putString("event_time", data.getString("event_recurring_text"));

                    } else {

                        bundle.putString("event_time", data.getString("event_time"));
                    }
                }
            }// end if



        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.i("Handler 4","JSONException: Handled");            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//Here data.has() method checking whether variable exists or not into oject

//vKj

Answer (score 1):

```
   {
        "PROJECT_NUMBER": ""
     },
```

Here you have only "PROJECT_NUMBER", reason you have the exception. Try to find a way to deal with it.

Comment: Are you responsible of the server side?

Comment: Okay then use has . Looks at @Pankaj Kumar answer

Answer (score 1):

You can check where key is exists or not using has() Method.
below is your code look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) 
    {

     JSONObject obj=innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);

     if(obj.has("PROJECT_NUMBER"))
     {
      Log.i("Project Number ",obj.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER"));
     }
     else
     {
        Log.i("Project Number ","No Such Tag as PROJECT_NUMBER");
     }

     if(obj.has("PROJECT_NAME"))
     {
       Log.i("Project Name ",obj.getString("PROJECT_NAME"));
     }
     else
     {
        Log.i("Project Name ","No Such Tag as PROJECT_NAME");
     }

}
```

I hope above code help you to resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jobject = innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (jobject .has("PROJECT_NUMBER")) {
        String strnumber = jobject .getString("PROJECT_NUMBER");
    }

    if (jobject .has("PROJECT_NAME")) {
        String strname= jobject .getString("PROJECT_NAME");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will help someone have this kind f issue, In my JSONarray name have space within double quotes, so the empty space consider as a character. this is kind of API issue. better request to remove the space otherwise developer will suffer.

```
"jobtype ": [
      {
        "id": "1006",
        "name": "Apprenticeship"
      }
    ]
```

LogCat:exception org.json.JSONException: No value for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (jsonObjectLeft.has("Left")) {

                    if (jsonObjectLeft.getJSONArray("Left") != null && 

jsonObjectLeft.getJSONArray("Left").length() > 0) {

                        jsonArrayLeft.put(jsonObjectLeft);

                        jsonObject.put("12", jsonArrayLeft);

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < innerProjectarray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = innerProjectarray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (obj.has("PROJECT_NUMBER")) {
        String projectnumber1 = obj.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER");
    }

    if (obj.has("PROJECT_NAME")) {
        String projectname1 = obj.getString("PROJECT_NAME");
    }
}
```