# Error reading web service with android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to read some JSON data from a web service and show it in a Toast.
This is the JSON array I'm trying to read:

```
{"ProximoPartido":[{"rival":"Nacional","cancha":"Stockolmo","hora":"21.15","fecha":"Viernes 30","estado":"Pendiente"}]}
```

This is te code I wrote:

```
private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject ProximosPartidos =
                    new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("ProximoPartido"));

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    ProximosPartidos.getString("rival") +
                            " - " + ProximosPartidos.getString("fecha"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> Value [{"hora":"21.15","estado":"Pendiente","fecha":"Viernes 30","rival":"Nacional","cancha":"Stockolmo"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONObject ProximosPartidos = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("ProximoPartido"));
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ProximosPartidos.getString("rival") +
                " - " + ProximosPartidos.getString("fecha"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProximoPartido");
  JSONObject ProximosPartidos =data.getJSONObject(0);
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ProximosPartidos.getString("rival") +                                                   
               " - " + ProximosPartidos.getString("fecha"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

As value of **result** is `JsonArray` not `JSONObject`.

**Edit**

Use [has](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to check if key is present in Json. It returns true if this object has a mapping for name.

```
  if (ProximosPartidos.has("rival") && ProximosPartidos.has("fecha")) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ProximosPartidos.getString("rival") +                                                   
                   " - " + ProximosPartidos.getString("fecha"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I replaced that piece of code and now I get this error:

No value for {"ProximoPartido":[{"rival":"Nacional","cancha":"Stockolmo","hora":"21.15","fecha":"Viernes 30","estado":"Pendiente"}]}

Comment: Ok I did it :D

BTW: You have idea what that new error means? Thanks!

Comment: @Bruno please elaborate more

Comment: I replaced my code for the one you just posted and now I get this error: "No value for {"ProximoPartido":[{"rival":"Nacional","cancha":"Stockolmo","hora":"21.15","fech‌​a":"Viernes 30","estado":"Pendiente"}]}".

I don't know what this error means.
Also, what means the zero here: =data.getJSONObject(0); ?

Comment: @Bruno 0 means first object of json array.

Comment: @Bruno see edited answer. and for more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043243/error-org-json-jsonexception-no-value-for-project-name-this-is-my-json

Comment: Ok, so seeing that I have only one object it's ok.
Well, I'll try something else.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see I should replaced my code where I show the data.
Anyway why could be the key the problem?

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I just replaces de zero to "ProximoPartido".
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSONObject is actually a JSONArray because it starts with `[]``

Just parse it like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject ProximosPartidos =
                new JSONObject(jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProximoPartido").getJSONObject(0));
```

and then the rest should work